# Is there any way to check chrome chrome://flags/ values using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i want to check if a **[Disable accelerated 2D canvas]** `chrome://flags/` was set to Disable or Enabled using java script on page load. is there any way ?

Comment: Do you *really* need to care about some - probably unlikely - browser configuration change?

Comment: using `NaCl` maybe. Otherwise, I don't think so.

Comment: i just only need to prompt the user "please enable the Disable accelerated 2D canvas settings in  chrome://flags/" if its disables..

Comment: @Cthulhu how can i use NaCl properties in java script ?

Comment: @Lijo There used to be something called `naclwtf`. I can't seem to find it. [This](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient-sdk/source/list?path=/branches/cod/src/examples/index.html&start=1397) seems to mention it

Comment: I would be *really* surprised and would proceed to kill Chrome with fire if I found out it allows JScripts know its core settings. On a side note: what if your users have disabled javascript ?

Comment: @Alex , Cthulh plz check this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/flot-graphs/qenufGRNGjY  this issue occurred only in up to dated chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m. in this version about:flags Disable accelerated 2D canvas was set to disable by default. So i want to recognize if the users browser disable the settings Disable accelerated 2D canvas using java script.

Comment: No you can't. You *must not* be able to. Javascript *must not* be able to access your local resources. You'd otherwise be facing remotely issued `rm -rf /`...

Answer (score 1):

Well, try to answer the question behind: Is user's canvas hardware accelerated?

With a GPU canvas there is virtually no difference in time between a drawImage() onto a rotated and a non rotated context. Comparing same operations with a canvas running on CPU yields big differences.